# I have an insecure API (HTTP) that I'm trying to access and Chrome blocks the data. Any way to work around this?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, api

I'm working with an api that is formatted in XML and it hasn't been secured/received an SSL certificate (HTTPS). Is there a way to bypass this and display the data?

I've tested to make sure it wasn't my code that was the problem. I'm using a simple fetch to output the code in my console. It works properly with other secure api's like the star wars api.

```
fetch(Url)
.then(data => {
  return data.xml()
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})

I'm just trying to output basic data in either JSON or XML format
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to interact with an insecure API? Even if the data isn't sensetive, it's really not good practice, just use [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get a quick certificate for your server.

Answer (score 3):

When on an HTTPS connection, you cannot connect to an HTTP endpoint like you're trying.

The best solution would be to fix the API so that it supports HTTPS, but if that's not possible, you can bounce the request off of your own (HTTPS-enabled) backend, have that backend make the HTTP request to the API, and have your backend reply with the response it receives.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for your own testing and not for a production facing site I'd try adding the http endpoint to this Chrome flag:

[image]

You can get to Chrome flags by putting `chrome://flags` in the Chrome address bar.

[image]

Note: I haven't tested this. It's entirely possible this is only useful for "powerful features" as described [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins).